# use postcss-cssnext and postcss-import

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, postcss, postcss-import

Hi I'm trying to use postcss-import and postcss-cssnext with grunt in an angular project. 
I have a colors.css file imported in main.css.

In gruntfile I'm calling first postcss-import plugin and then postcss-cssnext. But the import is not working when I use both plugins.

Anyway If I only call postcss-import it works fine, adding colors.css inside main.css.

```
postcss: {
      options: {
        processors: [
          require("postcss-import")()
          require("postcss-cssnext")({browsers: ['ie >= 8', 'last 2 versions']})
        ]
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          map: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use postcss-import along with postcss-cssnext because postcss-import is already added in [package.json](https://github.com/MoOx/postcss-cssnext/blob/master/package.json) of postcss-next.